# Module install: script install.mysql.utf8.sql does not create table

Tags: joomla, module

The SQL install script `install.mysql.utf8.sql` does not create the table.

My module manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
<name>Data Entry module</name>
<author>Md Masum</author>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<description>This is a data entry module. by this module we can store various data in our custom table into joomla database</description>
<files>
    <filename>mod_entry.xml</filename>
    <filename module="mod_entry">mod_entry.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    <folder>sql</folder>
</files>

<install>
<sql>
 <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
 <file driver="sqlazure"   charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/install.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
</sql>
</install>

<uninstall>
<sql>
 <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
 <file driver="sqlazure" charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/uninstall.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
</sql>
</uninstall>

<update> 
<schemas>
<schemapath type="mysql">sql/mysql/updates</schemapath> 
<schemapath type="sqlazure">sql/sqlazure/updates</schemapath> 
</schemas> 
</update>


<config>
</config>
</extension>
```

SQL file (install.mysql.utf8.sql) contains:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__student_profile` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` text NOT NULL,
`roll` int(10) NOT NULL,
`class` int(2) NOT NULL,
`section` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`subject` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`father_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`mother_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`phone` int(14) NOT NULL,
`date_birth` date NOT NULL,
`date_addmission` date NOT NULL,
`religion` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(6) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: This is new module. No one hv module imstalled this

Answer (score 2):

1. Manifest file is OK.
2. SQL file is also OK.

I've managed to install your module without any issues.

My guess is that you already have the module installed. If the module is already registered with Joomla, when creating the install kit and installing it, it will detect that it's already installed and it will NOT install it again but it will just update it (using the SQL update statements). Which means that `install.mysql.utf8.sql` will not get executed a second time.

Uninstall the module from Joomla and do a fresh reinstall, it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: any known reason if only the sql update statements doesn't run?